# Climate zones on a tiny world

Tags: climate, size

Suppose you have what it takes to build a Ringworld, or at least a Culture Orbital, but instead you make a tiny scale model of Earth, with a neutronium core to make the surface gravity match, a membrane to prevent atmosphere loss, and whatever else it takes to make surface conditions (other than curvature) match those of Earth.

If this toy world is small enough, wind and water carry heat quickly enough to make temperature mostly the same all over.  So: How big must it be to prevent that, so that latitude makes a noticeable difference in climate?

A comment justly says ‘noticeable’ is too vague, so how about this: the world must have icecaps (or at least permafrost) and tropical lands where ice is unknown.

Comment: I'd try to find real islands with different climates.

Comment: I think you need to better define "a noticeable difference". It's not like it is a binary value.

Comment: Geography /air /water currents have at least much, or can indeed can have more more to do with climate than the angle the sun rays hit the planet surface.  You can isolate wind and water currents so that they mimic a gradient in surface temperatures and rainfall across a broad range in a relatively tiny area.  Considering Son Doong Cave can generate it's own weather (in a sense), it is only ~10 miles X ~500 ft.

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about having the technology to create a small planet is that it will let you build in methods of controlling the climate. The builders would need to add heat pump technology to the right areas to compensate for the spreading of heat. The polar regions would pump the heat out to cool it. That heat would be sent to the equatorial regions to heat up that location. If you have the energy to build a planet, you have the energy to move heat between two (or more) areas on said planet. You could do this as a way that mimics underwater hydrothermal vents. These vents would not only allow you to move temperature around the planet, but also to add nutrients into the ocean which would be lacking due to the absence of geothermal activity.

Answer (score 0):

### Your [neutronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutronium) core is already cold.

In order for your nutronium core to have the desired effect you're going to have to pack a lot of matter in there. That's not a problem because neutron matter is nicely compressible as it is not electrically charged.

That said, it is not infinitely compressible, and your really tiny world might need more than you can fit inside it with compression alone. We need to get colder.

Since your world has neutronium based toys, I think it would be safe to say that extremely energy efficient little freezers could plausibly exist.

You could recycle this coldness and have it physically connected to the poles of your tiny world, causing water already there (and maybe actual water molecules in the air to condense) and form ice. The method of transfer could be passive or active. Passive would require less energy, but an active system (live valves etc) would allow you control over it enough to make seasons. Bigger ice caps in winter vs summer?

Unfortunately you would also need a heater connected to the equator, depending on how tiny the world was. If it's room sized you probably wouldn't - but if it's marble sized you definitely would. A heater would add the benefit of actually making the equator hot, rather than just a little colder than room temp.

That said - I have made a little leap from neutronium core toys to tiny kitchen appliances - so my answer may not be in scope for your world.

TL;DR - control the temperature using technology within the little earth.

p.s. lots of toys run on batteries.. Put a hinge somewhere on it and the worlds smallest star head screw.